# the row no in query output

Tags: sql, sql-server-2000, row-number

I have  a numeric field (say num) in table along with pkey.

```
select * from mytable order by num
```

now how I can get the row no in query output of a particular row for which I have pkey.

I'm using sql 2000.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like you want a row number for each record returned.

In SQL 2000, you can either do this:

```
SELECT (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM MyTable t2 WHERE t2.num <= t.num) AS RowNo, *
FROM MyTable t
ORDER BY num
```

which assumes num is unique. If it's not, then you'd have to use the PK field and order by that.

Or, use a temp table (or table var):

```
CREATE TABLE #Results
(
RowNo INTEGER IDENTITY(1,1),
MyField VARCHAR(10)
)

INSERT #Results
SELECT MyField
FROM MyTable 
ORDER BY uum

SELECT * FROM #Results

DROP TABLE #Results
```

In SQL 2005, there is a ROW_NUMBER() function you could use which makes life a lot easier.

Comment: first sol works if I have only 1 field, for more than 1 it doesn't.
How I can work with temp tables in ado.net?

Comment: Personally, I'd wrap the query into a stored procedure and then just call that. You could just send the query in as-is (CommandType=CommandType.Text).

Answer (score 0):

as i understand your question you want to get the number of all rows returned, right?
if so use [@@rowcount](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187316.aspx)

Comment: lol! yeah i've had a lot of practice with weirdly worded questions in the past :)

Comment: I want serial no of particular row (not of all rows) in query result.

Answer (score 0):

As Ada points out, this task became a lot easier in SQL Server 2005....

```
SELECT whatever, RowNumber from (
     SELECT pk
           , whatever
          , ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY num) AS 'RowNumber'
    FROM mytable
)
WHERE pk = 23;
```

Comment: ROW_NUMBER() function is not available in sql 2000